# Django manage.py Unknown command: 'syncdb'

Tags: python, django, django-syncdb, syncdb

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.creativebloq.com/netmag/get-started-django-7132932) but I'm stuck on the 5th step.

When I execute

[~/Django Projects/netmag$] `python manage.py syncdb`

I get the following error message :

```
Unknown command: 'syncdb'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

and here is the output of `./manage.py help` does not contain `syncdb` command. How do I add it?

Thanks for any help!

### Edit :

When I run migrate, I get this error :

> "Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes "
>   RuntimeError: Error creating new content types. Please make sure
>   contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.

in settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'blog',
]
```

### Edit 2:

If I remove `'blog',` from settings.py :

```
:~/Django Projects/netmag$ python manage.py migrate blog
CommandError: App 'blog' does not have migrations. 

:~/Django Projects/netmag$ python manage.py makemigrations blog 
App 'blog' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?
```

Comment: Did you edit the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?  You should place your app after the all django apps in this list.  BTW, I suggest you to use the official tutorial to learn the django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: @catavaran Thanks. I will try this tutorial tomorrow. Also I'm adding the INSTALLED_APPS list to the question.

Answer (score 197):

`syncdb` command is [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) in django 1.7.  Use the `python manage.py migrate` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised that Google didn't bring that to my attention :D

Comment: Try to remove your app from the `INSTALLED_APPS` and run `migrate` again.  The error still occurs?

Comment: I pasted the result in the question

Comment: Hm.  Return the `blog` back to the `INSTALLED_APPS` and then run `python manage.py migrate contenttypes`?

Comment: You can run `manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` if you have old applications that don't have migrations.

Answer (score 14):

You have to use `python manage.py migrate` instead rather than `python manage.py syncdb`

Answer (score 13):

*Run* `python manage.py makemigrations` *result below*

```
Migrations for 'blog':
blog/migrations/0001_initial.py:
- Create model Blog
```

*and after that run* `python manage.py migrate` *result below*

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, blog, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying article.0001_initial... OK
```

Answer (score 6):

the actual command is :

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

It will solve many errors in django like , Operational error ,No Table found in databse etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in stages, let's say you have an app called "example":

1. Run python manage.py makemigrations example
2. A number generates like '0001' get the number
3. Run python manage.py sqlmigrate example 0001, using the number. Check out the scripts.
4. Run python manage.py migrate example 0001

You can also look at all your migrations like this: `python manage.py showmigrations`.
If you don't want to commit it, go to the folder and move it somewhere or delete it before doing step 4.

Answer (score 0):

However, there is another error that can be happened as strict mode needs to be enabled for MariaDB.

Keep Database connection in the settings.py file as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'test',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'sql_mode': 'traditional',
    }
}
```

}

keep in mind about the below code:

```
'OPTIONS': {
        'sql_mode': 'traditional',
    }
```

After all, if your DJango version is backdated, "python manage.py syncdb" will work but for an updated version more than or equal to 1.7, please use "python manage.py migrate"

Thanks